# Starting the rails, sqlite3 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I start checking that the versions are appropriate, after checking that my system meets the minimum requirements:
`rails new app`
When zero the new application I get the message NEXT:

```
         run  bundle install
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/ui.rb:36:in `initialize': undefined method `[]' for #<Thor::Shell::Color:0x95890e0> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:12:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'
```

entered the newly created Rails application. I run `bundle install` thereupon start to install and get the following error message:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local


Gem files will remain installed in /home/helio/.bundler/tmp/23089/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/helio/.bundler/tmp/23089/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

---

I've tried but I get an error message when I try to install splite3:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I've also tried to write the two lines which advises the message:      `port install sqlite3 +universal` and `yum install sqlite-devel` and nothing those dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in Gemfile. There is a note in the tutorial that says: Windows and Mac has installed the java runtime script too, by default. Instead linux does not carry it. It must be installed separately. But it is very easy to solve
The first is to clear the line that refers to the runtime, in the Gemfile.
The second is `bundle install`. Bundler to run this command installs the necessary software and boala, solved.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error, trying to start a new Rails project. In this case `sqlite3.h is missing`, means that *libsqlite3-dev* is missing, I guess (I'm new with Ubuntu and Sqlite3).  The answer can be found right here : [Installing sqlite headers](http://www.databasically.com/2010/03/05/installing-sqlite-headers-on-ubuntu-sqlite3-h-not-found/).

```
~$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
~$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
~$ bundle install
```

After that, `rails server` worked well for me. I had my *Welcome aboard* in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install sqlite3 on your system first. Rails is missing the libraries here.

Comment: just edit the entry with the result after trying to install sqlite3

Comment: sqlite3 is instaled                                                   `SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> `

Answer (score 1):

For me I got the error (on MacOS) that turned out to be a missing GNU MP library.

This was mentioned in the ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9/mkmf.log file

-lgmp was missing

brew showed the libs as existing, but I think Xcode wanted to know:

My trail...

$ brew install gmp
Warning: gmp-6.0.0a already installed
✔ ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9

$ brew install gmp4
Warning: gmp4-4.3.2 already installed
✔ ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9

$ ls -altd /usr/local/lib/libgmp*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 si  staff  40 Jul 31 15:48 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib -> ../Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 si  staff  33 Jul 31 15:48 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a -> ../Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmp.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 si  staff  37 Jul 31 15:48 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib -> ../Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmp.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 si  staff  41 Jul 31 15:48 /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib -> ../Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 si  staff  35 Jul 31 15:48 /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.a -> ../Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmpxx.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 si  staff  39 Jul 31 15:48 /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.dylib -> ../Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmpxx.dylib
✔ ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9

$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
✔ ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9

$ gem install sqlite3 '1.3.9'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.9
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '1.3.9' (>= 0) in any repository
1 gem installed

Even though it gave this ERROR message, it still seemed to install ok